# Dojo button created programmatically-Scope problem

Tags: dojo, scope, dijit.form

Dear All,
I've created a new Dojo button programatically. I'm doing that in one of my custom dojo class. While creating the button, I've defined an onClick method which should be called when the button is clicked. This method is part of the class. I'm not able to invoke that method, since the scope of "`this`" is different when the button is clicked. Can some one please help me to do fix this?

```
dojo.declare("CustomClass",null,{
createCustomButton:function(){
var button = new dijit.form.Button({onClick:function(){
                    removetrack();
                    testDataGrid.filter({status:"COMPLETED"});
                }},"testButton1");
},
removetrack:function(){
//some logic
}
});


var customObj=new CustomClass();
customObj.createCustomButton();
```

I need `removetrack()` method to be called when I click on the Button created.

Comment: It's not clear from your question which scope you want removetrack() to be called in. I'll answer below assuming it's the scope of this within createCustomButton, but if that's wrong please clarify and I'll see if I can change my answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dojo.hitch();

```
dojo.declare("CustomClass",null,{
    createCustomButton:function(){
        var button = new dijit.form.Button({
            onClick:dojo.hitch(this, function(){
                this.removetrack();
                testDataGrid.filter({status:"COMPLETED"});
            })
        },"testButton1");
    },
    removetrack:function(){
        //some logic
    }
});


var customObj=new CustomClass();
customObj.createCustomButton();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I think we need to use this.removetrack().

Answer (score -1):

I cannot manage to do better way, in case you need urgent fix

```
var button = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: "Custom!",
                    onClick:function(){
                    CustomClass().removetrack();
                }},"result");
```

Hope someone can give you better option.

Comment: No, that won't work. That looks like there is a removetrack function attached to the CustomClass function.